# SQL Express connection issue

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, mdt-2012

I have installed a instance of sql-express for an MDT deployment solution (XYZ-Deployment) I've got to the stage where I add a database share and when I go to add it, I get the following error message. Everything is installed local.

[image]

I've tried log on as local, as service, changed from named pipes to tcp/ip and still get the same error, when I run -

Get-EventLog Application -EntryType Error -ComputerName xyz-deployment

there are no error's in the event log for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much messing around I decided to remove SQL fully and follow the instructions provided [here](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles-tutorials/windows-7/Deploying-Windows-7-Part15.html).

These instructions work a treat!

Answer (score 0):

RTE - Reat the error.

There are various reasons. Generally:

- Bad configuration of the db server (not listening to IP you try to reach). Did you check the configruration - as it says in the error?
- Firewall. People often overlook that - installing a SQL version does not add the necessary firewall exceptions.
- Crappy client side error. Seen that yesterday with aa guy copying his local connection string to the client machine - and the connection string said the server name was "localhost" - which obviously did not work.

Btw., you do not add file shares, sql server is server based.

Comment: I tried to edit my above post to add in the below config manager part, i have turned off the firewall and also reinstalled sqlexpress and its still not working. the two services are disabled.

Answer (score 0):

SQLExpress requires you to include the instance name.

```
localhost\SQLEXPRESS
```

From the SQL Server Management Studio help:

> In most cases, you can connect by entering the computer name of the
>   database server in the Server name box and then clicking Connect. If
>   you are connecting to SQL Server Express, use the computer name
>   followed by \sqlexpress

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using ODBC wizard to connect on the local machine such as localhost\SQLExpress to see if it is authentication or connectivity that is your issue?

Default install is ..\SQLExpress as stated by my esteemed colleague and port number is dynamic by default but it may be worth setting it to 1433 and opening the port in the machines firewall if you are still not connecting via ODBC.

Once you have discovered the settings you need from the ODBC settings under administrative tools then you can use these to properly connect to your database.